# Unable to list my Developer ID Application identity

Tags: macos, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I follow the instructions here to generate the certificates for signing my application: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devbfa00fef7

Unfortunately, I'm unable to codesign my application with the following command:

```
codesign --sign "Developer ID Application: My company (XXXXXX)" Test.app --deep
Developer ID Application: My company (XXXXXX): no identity found
```

I tried to list my identity with the following command without success:

```
security find-identity

Policy: X.509 Basic
  Matching identities
  1) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Distribution: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  2) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  3) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Development: Martin Delille (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  4) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Distribution: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  5) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Development: Martin Delille (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  6) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Mac Developer: Martin Delille (XXXXXXXXXX)"
     6 identities found

  Valid identities only
  1) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Distribution: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  2) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  3) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Development: Martin Delille (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  4) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Distribution: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  5) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Apple Development: Martin Delille (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  6) xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "Mac Developer: Martin Delille (XXXXXXXXXX)"
     6 valid identities found
```

As you can see, my *Developer Id Application* certificate is located in my keychain:

[image]

Comment: The certificate is in the keychain, certainly, but it won't show up as a "valid identity" unless you also have the key. Usually Keychain Access will show a disclosure triangle next to any certificate for which you have the key. It is not visible in your example.

Comment: Thanks @gaige! I fixed my problem by exporting the private key of another machine that was able to sign to the new one and it runs fine now! If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate is in the keychain, certainly, but it won't show up as a "valid identity" unless you also have the key. Usually Keychain Access will show a disclosure triangle next to any certificate for which you have the key. It is not visible in your example.